# How do I login to the Django Rest browsable API when I have a custom auth model?

Tags: python, django, rest, authentication

I have a custom user model as follows in `account/models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.modles import AbstractUser
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)                                
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):               
    if created:                                                                      
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)                                          

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):                                                     
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,default='')
```

and in `settings.py`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

...

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "account.UserProfile"
```

However, whenever I try to log into the browsable API, it asks me to use a correct username and password, and I am using credentials of users who are both marked as superusers and staff.

The `manage.py runserver` console shows this status message:

```
[27/Jul/2016 20:41:39] "POST /api-auth/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2897
```

Answer (score 12):

I've ran into this before too and from what I remember it's because the built-in DRF auth form is not using TokenAuthentication, but rather SessionAuthentication. Try adding `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` to your `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` tuple

Comment: Alright, that works, but now it's redirecting to `accounts/profile` after login. What is the URL/page actually supposed to be? When I go to (...)/api-auth/, the only valid patterns it gives are `api-auth/ ^login/$` and `api-auth/ ^logout/$`.

Comment: that is a setting `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url

Comment: keep in mind that you have multiple authentication methods. So with this method (session) you're going to be redirected to the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`. However TokenAuthentication is different, and it will just respond with the token and not redirect. Just thought I'd add this in case you had concerns about not wanting to redirect to the same place when you use TokenAuthentication

Comment: Well, the main issue I am having with that is the fact that it doesn't appear that the `include('rest_framework.urls')` statement in `urls.py` actually generates a URL for viewing the browsable API, and I don't know what that URL is supposed to be. Because of that, I don't know what to redirect the login to.

Comment: ah yeah that's always annoying. A little workaround i do is go to a url i know will return a 404 and it will show you all the urls (with name i.e. 'account-detail') that are generated magically through ViewSets. You can use that in a reverse, or just hardcode the url and then after session login it will redirect there.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no url patterns that would seem to produce a page that would contain the browsable API. I have no idea why this is.

Answer (score 7):

Django Rest Framework "Login to browsable API" uses session authentication rather than token authentication. To add login to the browsable API follow the steps below:

Step 1 : Add the following in the 'urls.py' file in your project.

```html
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns += [path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),]
```

Step 2 : You have added only TokenAuthentication in 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES', you need to add sessionAuthentication as well. Change your code as below:

```html
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    ),
```

Now both your Token authentication for your custom authentication, and Session Authentication for Browsable API will work.

Comment: thanks for sharing, actually I also only needed api in my project. but for testing purpose need session auth as well.