# 405 error when custom-defined PATCH method is called for Django REST APIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-405

I am making an API call in the test client:

```
response2 = self.client.patch('/object/update/%d/' %
                                object_id, {'object_attribute':4})
```

The relevant serializer and view class for the object:

```
class ObjectUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Object
        include=('object_attribte','another_attribute',)

class ObjectView(APIView):
    def patch(self, request, pk, format=None):
        obj = Object.objects.get(id=pk)
        data = request.data.copy()
        """do some stuff with the data here..."""
        serializer = ObjectUpdateSerializer(instance = obj, data=data,
                                            partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data,status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I was able to work with the PUT method when I used that, but I wanted to have the API call methods be more in-line with what the methods actually mean (so PATCH would be a partial replacement). However, the response to the test client call above is this:

```
{u'detail': u'Method "PATCH" not allowed.'}
```

Which is a 405 error (method not allowed).

I checked to see if there were any issues with Django 1.10, and I also got this output in the django shell:

```
>>> from django.views.generic import View
>>> View.http_method_names
[u'get', u'post', u'put', u'patch', u'delete', u'head', u'options', u'trace']
```

It appears as if it isn't an issue with Django's settings, but something that I've set up. What could be the issue here?

Comment: I am guessing you are sending the PATCH Request to the wrong URL. Can we see the client side code or preferably a `curl` command showing your error.

Comment: The method works when I replace "patch" with "put", i.e.,

`def patch(...) -> def put(...)` and

`self.client.patch -> self.client.put`

Comment: That test is interesting, but it does not provide enough information for me to help. Try browsing to the [Browsable API](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/#urls) and see what HTTP requests DRF says you have enabled in your API view.

Comment: I cannot get the browsable API to work. That is another issue that I have had that remains unresolved.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623002/how-do-i-login-to-the-django-rest-browsable-api-when-i-have-a-custom-auth-model

Comment: You must ensure that all authentication mechanisms are working correctly before you can debug your API. If you turn off authentication temporarily, then you may be able to debug your RESTful interface.

Comment: Pretty sure this is the result of some misconfigured routes. Could you please also give us a snapshot of your urls.py and routers and custom routers (if any being used). Also ensure you are accessing this URL by giving a `pk`.

Comment: @MaxCandocia I know this is from a long time ago, but I'm wondering if you'd found the solution in which case I'd kindly ask you to share it with everyone here.

Comment: I think I may have just created the desired side effect from a different request type. Also, I stopped working on the project using that code about a month after this post.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. It appeared that it's not allowed to use different views for the same route:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url('^sessions/?$', views.TokenDelete.as_view()), # Viewer has delete()
    url('^sessions/?$', views.TokenEdit.as_view()),   # Viewer has patch()
]
```

The correct way is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url('^sessions/?$', views.Token.as_view()), # Viewer has both patch() and delete()
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if we have the exact same problem, but I got a problem with the same error code 405 using `@api_view(['PUT', 'DELETE'])` from rest_framework.

I solved it but reordering my urls in urlpatterns by putting the more specific urls before the others .e.g:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'$',
        views.swot_list,
        name='get_post'
    ),  
    url(
        r'(?P<swot_id>[0-9]+)/$',
        views.swot_detail,
        name='put_delete'
    ),
]
```

reordered into:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'(?P<swot_id>[0-9]+)/$',
        views.swot_detail,
        name='put_delete'
    ),
    url(
        r'$',
        views.swot_list,
        name='get_post'
    ),  
]
```

It turns out the order is important, and that makes sense to me. Hope this may be of help to anyone out there.